# Should foo.xcodeproj/xcuserdata be ignored in git repo?

Tags: xcode, git, xcode6, osx-yosemite

Using Xcode 6.1 beta 2, I created a new CLI app using Swift. With nothing changed, I noticed dirty files under the Xcode project directory:

```
$ git status
# On branch master
# Untracked files:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
#
#   letitsinkin.xcodeproj/xcuserdata/
nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)
```

Should I ignore 'xcuserdata' in .gitignore? So far, it contains two files:

```
letitsinkin.xcodeproj/xcuserdata/srid.xcuserdatad/xcschemes/letitsinkin.xcscheme
letitsinkin.xcodeproj/xcuserdata/srid.xcuserdatad/xcschemes/xcschememanagement.plist
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, ignore it. This data is only applicable to you. Others won't want it, or anything else in `xcuserdata`.

You may want to just use [GitHub's Objective-C `.gitignore` file](https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/Objective-C.gitignore), which is well-researched.

Comment: what about the xcuderdata files located in the `project.xcworkspace` package within the `.xcodeproj` file